# How to compile wget or curl with https support statically on armv5tejl?

Tags: wget, curl, arm, busybox, arch-arm

I have an IP camera with BusyBox. It has armv5tejl architecture
When I want to use wget to download something from https://....
When I try to use it with https I get an error:

```
wget: not an http or ftp url: https://...
```

I don't have curl. I don't have bash. Also I don't have apt-get or yum utilits.
I need to be able to send requests through https.
Where can I find wget for my architecture and how to use https?

Sincerely

Comment: Are you already setup to compile or cross-compile for the armv5 processor?

Comment: To use https URLs from wget, you need GnuTLS or OpenSSL or some other certificate verification utility on your system. You'll have to install those and then reinstall wget to get https to work.

Comment: No. There is no gcc but something else which doesn't work when I trying to compile something because it shows me an error that gcc haven't been found.